# Variable number of categories/checkboxes

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox, webforms

I am building a form for parents to enter health information for their students. Our nurses want to build it similar to what you fill out when you see a new doctor where they have categories and then conditions within the category that you would check if they apply to you. They want the number of categories and conditions to be variable so they can change them willy nilly as desired.

I need some ideas as to how to approach the UI side. My initial thought is a parent gridview with a row for each category and then inside that, a child gridview for each condition with its own checkbox. I already do a bit of work with gridviews and know how to access the nested objects so I'm not terribly worried about how to get the data back.

My question is this: Is there a better way and what suggestions would the community make that might be different or more efficient than using nested gridviews?

Comment: I think a asp:CheckBoxList control can replace the inner gridview instead of having 2 gridviews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 for asking *is there a better way?*

What I'm about to suggest may end up being a little more complicated at first, but rest assured it will be worth it in the end.

There is a JavaScript framework named `Knockout.js` that is perfect for situations like these. Knockout vastly simplifies situations that where a variable amount of UI controls are needed.

http://knockoutjs.com/

Here is a tutorial on the website that has a similar situation to yours: 
http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections

Comment: In the interest of time (project is due August 1), since I don't know much about javascript, I'm going to go with the gridview and checkboxlist controls for now. Once we get started into our school year and things settle down, I'm going to re-visit this and see what I can do to convert it.