# ASP/HTML Dynamic Checkbox Groups

Tags: html, dynamic, checkbox, asp-classic

I have a page that I am generating that needs to have a variable number of entries pulled from a database and then use checkboxes to add data to another table in the databse.

Basically I will pull a list of names from a database and then there will be 4 yes/no conditions that will be added to each of those entries and the results will be shipped off to another database.

This is what I have now:

```html
<%
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.open "--connection information here--"
SQL = "Select firstname,lastname from [names] order by lastname"
Set RS = Conn.Execute(SQL)
%>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Condition One</th>
    <th>Condition Two</th>
    <th>Condition Three</th>
    <th>Condition Four</th>
  </tr>
  <% Do While Not RS.EOF %>
  <tr>
    <td><%=RS("LastName")%>, <%=RS("FirstName")%></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <%
    RS.MoveNext
    Loop
  %>
</table>
```

<sub>I know I dont have any identifying attributes for the checkboxes such as `name` or `id`, this is because I am not sure how to do this dynamically in the loop so that the data is grouped together the way I need it. Also please disregard any syntax errors I may have made in the above code, I retyped this rather than copy/pasting my actual code so I could make it more readable and protect sensitive information while showing you what I am working with. The actual page uses the exact same formatting and structure as above and works fine as it is.</sub>

This generates the page looking like I want but I need to then go back and retrieve the information in groups with the name and corresponding conditions together so I can then input the information in the correct places in the second table.

How can I label or structure this so I can pull the information I need out?

Now, I have found the question posting [[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246140/variable-number-of-categories-checkboxes]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246140/variable-number-of-categories-checkboxes%5d) but the only answer there uses an outside script. I need to be able to do this without including outside script for the project I am working on.

Comment: Have you got an ID against [Names]?

Comment: I'm sorry, I dont quite understand what your asking...

Comment: In your names table.. do you have an ID field?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, been really busy. Yes I do have an ID Field, it is the key for the table and is auto-incremented when a new entry is added.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.open "--connection information here--"
SQL = "Select ID,firstname,lastname from [names] order by lastname"
Set RS = Conn.Execute(SQL)
%>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Condition One</th>
    <th>Condition Two</th>
    <th>Condition Three</th>
    <th>Condition Four</th>
  </tr>
  <% Do While Not RS.EOF %>
  <tr>
    <td><%=RS("LastName")%>, <%=RS("FirstName")%></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="Cond_1_<%=RS("ID")%>"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="Cond_2_<%=RS("ID")%>"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="Cond_3_<%=RS("ID")%>"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="Cond_4_<%=RS("ID")%>"></td>
  </tr>
  <%
    RS.MoveNext
    Loop
  %>
</table>
```